# localstorage to save text properties

Tags: javascript

I'm building a website where I can create an account and use a Texteditor which is a div. I want to enable to save written text and I'm using localstorage for that. Unfortunately, when I refresh the page, only the text is saved not the applied properties like bold, italic, underline, alignmentLeft, right and center. Is there a way to save this to?

I know exeComand is deprecated but I couldn't find and alternative:

My javascript to modify the text:

```
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let fontStyle = button.dataset['element'];
  document.execCommand(fontStyle, false, null);
  storeText();
})
});
```

My javascript to store and upload the text

```
 function storeText() {
  const textfield = document.getElementById("textfield");
  const text = textfield.textContent;
  localStorage.setItem("text", text);
}

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.getElementById("textfield.textContent").textContent = localStorage.getItem("text");
});
}
```

Comment: You would have to save the markdown/html RichText version of the text to LocalStorage.

Comment: how is the html being displayed on the screen? presumably there is markup for all that being controlled someplace. maybe show your html.

Comment: I'have edited the text how can I do that Mr. Polywhirl?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using **textContent** and not **innerHTML**?? textContent gets just the text, innerHTML gets the HTML tags also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using innerHTML works instead of textContent since textContent gets just the text with no HTML.

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons");
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let fontStyle = button.dataset['element'];
    document.execCommand(fontStyle, false, null);
    storeText();
  })
});

function storeText() {
  const textfield = document.getElementById("textfield");
  const text = textfield.innerHTML;
  localStorage.setItem("text",text)
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("textfield").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("text");
  })
```